# Is there an application for generating image for Windows Store Application?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-8

I'm a developer and i'm not designer at all :)
I developped application for windows phone and windows store but i always has difficulties when it comes to create image in different size (splashscreen, tile, badge, etc...)

Is there an application that generate all the size needed for a windows store app based on given image?

Thank you,

Kind Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Metro Studio 2](http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/metrostudio) is great tool that has large number of icons/images available 
. Take a look.